# Excel sheet made in Windows showing "#NAME?" error on MAC

Tags: excel, windows, macos

I've made an Excel sheet on my Microsoft Office 365, on Windows. It works like a charm on every PC that I run it. BUT, when my boss tried to run it on his MAC and on another coworker's MAC, there were *#NAME?* errors EVERYWHERE! His office is pretty old (2011), but my coworkers is the same Office 365 as mine.

I've done some research about this *#NAME?* thing, but I couldn't find any reason why my sheet work flawlessly on Windows and totally crashes on MAC.

Below some info that can be usefull:

- I'm saving my sheet as .xmsm, as it got a little macro to hide the workbook tabs(that is working perfectly on MAC, by the way).
- It is a protected sheet, as it was made for public sharing.
- These are ALL the formulas used in my sheet: SUM, SUMIF, IF, IFS, AND, OR and TEXT.
- There are two cells that have similar formulas, only one shows *#NAME?* error.

Comment: What are the actual formulas that're getting #NAME? errors? Especially, show the similar ones that're working vs not working.

Comment: I'll use T14 as an example:

T14:
`=TEXT(CALC!$G$12;"R$ #.##0,00")`

CALC!G12:
`=C12*E12`

E12:
`=SUMIF(CONFIG!C2:C7;CALC!$D$3;CONFIG!E2:E7)`

C12:
60

Comment: T14 shows #NAME? on MAC. T25 doesn't.

T25: `=TEXT(CALC!$G$23;"R$ #.##0,00")`
CALC!G23: `=SUMIF(CONFIG!O2:O7;CALC!$I$3;CONFIG!P2:P7)`